# Call Repository class in service Layer in C# and dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dapper

I like [DAL with dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246977/dal-with-dapper-and-c-sharp/38259907#38259907) approach and looking at doing something similar myself. how  to use the Base repository class and then how to calling those from Service Tier? I also use transaction scope in service tier..Please any one give a sample solution to pass the arguements in service layer? or any alternative solution?

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly IComplianceConnection Connection;

    public Repository(IComplianceConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Get(string query, object arguments)
    {
        IList<T> entities;

        using (var connection = Connection.OpenConnection())
        {
            entities = connection.Query<T>(query, arguments, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
        }

        return entities;
    }

    public T GetSingleOrDefault(string query, object arguments)
    {
        T entity;

        using (var connection = Connection.OpenConnection())
        {
            entity =
                connection.Query<T>(query, arguments, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
        }

        return entity;
    }

    public void Update(string query, object arguments)
    {
        using (var connection = Connection.OpenConnection())
        {
            connection.Execute(query, arguments, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }

    public int ExecuteScalar(string query, object arguments)
    {
        var id = 0;
        using (var connection = Connection.OpenConnection())
        {
            id = connection.ExecuteScalar<int>(query, arguments, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really need to ask yourself what is the value-added of this style of class. The fact that there is nothing specific to your app domain should set off alarm bells. Your class essentially adds (very basic) management of the connection, and sets the command type to `StoredProcedure`, but it removes the possibility of any other command type, and any other type of connection management: transactions, working directly with IEnumerable (and avoid hogging memory with a large result set)

A good reason for skinning Dapper would be to provide a 'repo' that could be mocked, to let you unit-test calling code. This class could do that, but you would be better with an interface, and better with something that didn't drastically restrict the possibilities of Dapper.